# ./configure failed, error: Gentoo sanity check failed

Tags: c++, linux

I was compiling ZThread-2.3.2 from [this site](http://zthread.sourceforge.net).

After unpacking the tar.gz file. In the root directory of ZThread-2.3.2 I ran the command

`./configure --prefix=/home/Documents/zthread`

After a while it gave me an error

```
*** Gentoo sanity check failed! ***
*** libtool.m4 and ltmain.sh have a version mismatch! ***
*** (libtool.m4 = 1.5.10, ltmain.sh = ) ***

Please run:

  libtoolize --copy --force

if appropriate, please contact the maintainer of this
package (or your distribution) for help.
```

Then I executed this command as required:

`libtoolize --copy --force`

But it still gave me error message:

```
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: You should add the contents of the following files to `aclocal.m4':
libtoolize:   `/usr/share/aclocal/libtool.m4'
libtoolize:   `/usr/share/aclocal/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize:   `/usr/share/aclocal/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize:   `/usr/share/aclocal/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize:   `/usr/share/aclocal/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.ac and
libtoolize: rerunning libtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
```

I checked the version of `libtool` as below:

`libtool --version`

It says libtool version is 2.4.2:

```
libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.2
Written by Gordon Matzigkeit <gord@gnu.ai.mit.edu>, 1996

Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

What caused this problem? Is there anybody successfully installed ZThread ?

I know there are quite a lot threading libraries other than ZThread, I just want to know what went wrong.

Comment: `ltmain.sh` seams to have no version. Did you check this? Could you determine, how the sanity check detects the version?

Comment: This is better suited for SuperUser.

Comment: @harper yes I checked the `ltmain.sh` file. On line 49. `VERSION=1.5.10`. In fact, I'm a newbie to linux-style compilation & installation. For now I don't know how the sanity check detects the version. Any idea?

Comment: @OMGtechy You mean I should add `sudo` before `./configure` and then enter my password?

Comment: @lqr no, he means superuser.com . Anyway, did you try what the first link on google tells you? `autoreconf --force --install --symlink` ? it seems like some automake file version conflict to me

Comment: Hmm. Why not use the version in portage? dev-libs/zthread-2.3.2-r3 is in portage.

Comment: @PeterT I tried many solutions I could find on Google. `autoreconf --force --install --symlink` seems modified some file and when I run `./configure` again, it tells me another error, something like macro not defined.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, maybe this one would work. xD

Comment: At least that way you can get gentoo help..

Comment: Notice the last update date on ZThread ... its a noble effort to kick tires on various threading libs however current wisdom is to get threads from std::thread

Comment: also teach yourself about std::async and  std::promise

Answer (score 2):

I just installed ZThread on Ubuntu.

The reason that `ltmain.sh` has an empty version is because of a syntax error in the ./configure file. You should have the following error before `*** Gentoo sanity check failed! ***`:

```
checking for correct ltmain.sh version... grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]
no
```

The error is in the following line of the ./configure file:

```
gentoo_ltmain_version=`grep '^[:space:]*VERSION=' $ltmain | sed -e 's|^[:space:]*VERSION=||'`
```

After changing `[:space:]` to `[[:space:]]`, it becomes the following and should fix the issue:

```
gentoo_ltmain_version=`grep '^[[:space:]]*VERSION=' $ltmain | sed -e 's|^[:space:]*VERSION=||'`
```

It's likely that you will encounter a compilation error after this because  of a deprecated syntax used by ZThread, which you can fix by adding the following line to ./configure:

```
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fpermissive"
```

Comment: On Linux Mint 19 (based on Ubuntu 18.04) similar problem happens with 'sed'. so it's probably worth making similar change for sed expression.